# Переливающаяся как вода картинка

Tags: delphi

В установщике Delphi 7 Full Edition есть такая картинка (или область), которая на наведение указателя мыши ведёт себя как вода, в смысле, она переливается, как поверхность воды. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Посмотри](http://www.sources.ru/delphi/delphi_opengl.shtml), может поможет.

Comment: Хоть немного и не то, что надо, но всё равно! БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!